# Is there a word for a special kind of literature?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

In my own language we have a word which subscribes all literature that you you read to enjoy yourself, like a novel, historical, autobiography, sience fiction, tales etc. And it word down't include educational literature and other.
I found only words like 'fiction' or 'nonfiction' but i am a little confused which to use, because many novels are fiction and some not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a term *[belles lettres](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belles%20lettres)*:

> literature that is an end in itself and not merely informative; specifically : light, entertaining, and often sophisticated literature

Also [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095457456) describes it as

> The French term for ‘fine writing’, originally used (as in ‘fine art’) to distinguish artistic literature from scientific or philosophical writing. Since the 19th century, though, the term has more often been used dismissively to denote a category of elegant essay-writing and lightweight literary chatter, of which much was published in Britain in the late 19th and early 20th centuries: Max Beerbohm's essays and Andrew Lang's Letters to Dead Authors (1896) are examples. An author of such elegant trifles is a belletrist. Adjective: belletristic.

Although I have rather heard *fiction* as you state.

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fiction):

> *1 mass noun* Literature in the form of prose, especially novels, that describes imaginary events and people.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiction):

> *b* : fictitious literature (such as novels or short stories) * *was renowned as a writer of fiction*

And in my own language (Czech) we use *beletrie* in exactly the same meaning as you requested.

Answer (score 2):

I should note that some people *do* read educational material for pleasure. (And others can dislike fiction.)

So, unless you're making a distinction about the specific *content*, a phrase for this type of *activity* is **recreational reading**.

The article ["Why Recreational Reading is a Ticket to Success"](https://www.ool.co.uk/blog/recreational-reading-ticket-success/) actually puts the emphasis on activity in this way:

> Reading for pleasure can make a significant difference to your academic success. If you haven’t read a novel for a while, or you can’t even remember when you last picked up a book of any kind, here are some compelling reasons to get started . . .

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a word in English that has as its only meaning a categorization of different genres of writing by whether people read them in hope of pleasure. As a different answer pointed out, people have different tastes so any such categorization would be somewhat arbitrary or normative rather than universally descriptive.

English does have phrases that describe the activity of reading for pleasure.

However, the word "literature" itself has as one of its several meanings "writing intended to be read primarily for its own sake rather than for a primarily utilitarian purpose." A manual on cabinetry is not "literature" in that sense. We do not say that someone who writes a manual on cabinetry writes literature. We call that technical writing. Moreover the word "non-fiction" is frequently used to distinguish writings, e.g. biographies, histories, or essays, that are not fiction but that are not purely technical writing.